# Help with a better translation for 展示着它罕见和珍稀。

Tags: translation

The subject is '滇南红河的哀牢山‘ terraced fields.
话题是哈尼梯田。

1300多年，山民们用汗水，用心血，用日复一日的辛勤劳动完成了山脉上的雕刻，任何困难也阻拦不了它们。这幅画卷以其宝贵的生态、文化和审美价值，展示着它罕见和珍稀。

罕见：rarely seen
珍稀：rare, precious

展示着它罕见和珍稀。
reveals its rareness and preciousness.
reveals its rare and precious nature.
shows its uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

- reveal= 展露/显露 (*展示 means 'display'*)
- rareness= 罕有性 or 罕有 (*罕见 means 'rarely seen'*)
- preciousness= 珍贵性 or 珍贵 (*珍稀 means 'precious and rare'* )
- uniqueness= 独特性 or 独特

(*you can omit 性*)

> **reveals** its **rareness** and **preciousness**
>
> **展露**着它的**罕有性**和**珍贵性**
>
> **展露**着它的**罕有**和**珍贵**

~ 'rareness'(罕有性) and 'preciousness'(珍贵性) are nouns

> **reveals** its **rare and precious nature**.
>
> **展露**着它**罕有**和**珍贵的本质**

~ 'rare'(罕有的) and 'precious'(珍贵的) are adjectives

> **shows** its **uniqueness**.
>
> **显示**它的**独特性**

Answer (score 0):

shows how rare and precious they are.

demonstrates how rare and precious they are.